# Como recuperar el ultimo id generado en oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

Estoy tratando de capturar el último `id` registrado en una tabla (USO ORACLE 11G) y buscando en internet me encontre este [post](https://www.campusmvp.es/recursos/post/Auto-numericos-como-obtener-el-ultimo-insertado-en-Oracle-MySQL-y-SQL-Server.aspx.).

No encontre mucha informacion en español por eso solo estoy usando como referencia solo este post, pero no me funciona. En el post indica que hay que crear un trigger y luego capturar el `id` ingresado , a través de  un `returning into` pero al momento de ejecutar la sentencia de `insert` junto con el  `returning`  me da error,  pero si ejecuto solo el `insert`  no hay problema. En teoría debería ejecutarse las dos instrucciones juntas.

En concreto me da el sgt error:

> "ORA-01008: NOT ALL VARIABLES  BOUND".

```
/*CREANDO SECUENCIAS*/

create sequence id_pedido
 start with 1
 increment by 1;
/*CREO LA TABLA PADRE*/
create table pedidos_padre(
id_pedidos_padre int primary key,
id_usuario int,
fecha_registro date,
nom_cliente varchar(150),
foreign key(id_usuario)
references usuario(id_usuario)
);
/*creo un disparador para capturar el ultimo id generado*/

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER pedidos_padre_bit
BEFORE INSERT ON pedidos_padre
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SELECT id_pedido.NEXTVAL
  INTO   :new.id_pedidos_padre
  FROM   dual;
END;

insert into pedidos_padre(id_pedidos_padre,id_usuario,fecha_registro,nom_cliente)
values(id_pedido.nextval,2,sysdate,'rayito')
RETURNING id_pedidos_padre INTO :last_insert_id
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: ¿En qué contexto haces el insert? ¿Script, Procedimiento Almacenado, otro?

Answer (score 1):

te sirve si obtienes el mayor rowid de la tabla?

```
SELECT ID_PEDIDOS_PADRE
FROM PEDIDOS_PADRE
WHERE ROWID =
    (
    SELECT MAX(ROWID)
    FROM PEDIDOS_PADRE
    )
```

Comment: No es necesario obtener el rowid. Es más sencillo. Lo indico abajo

Answer (score 0):

Ya revisaste con `currval`?

```
SELECT id_pedido.CURRVAL from dual;
```

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Para saber el ID basta con que cojas el máximo

```sql
SELECT  MAX(IDPEDIDO) 
FROM PEDIDOS_PADRE
```

Si lo estás usando en un PL

```sql
SELECT MAX(IDPEDIDO) INTO variableDeSalida
FROM PEDIDOS_PADRE
```